# Arranging words in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is my implementation , i have a txt file where the animals are randomly assign. i want to order them and insert it into a list.

```
void SortedList::insert(std::string x){

    int insertPoint=0;

    if(top==n){
    n = 2 * n;
    string* temp = arr;
    arr = new string[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++){
            arr[i] = temp[i];
            }

        delete[] temp;
    }


    arr[top]=x;
    LinearOrdering();
    top++;

}
```

and

```
void SortedList::LinearOrdering(){

    for(int i=0; i < top ; i++){

    if (arr[i] > arr[ i + 1]) {
            swap (arr[i], arr[i+1]);
        }

    }

}
```

this is my result

```
aardvark
baboon
cougar
gorilla
lion
mouse
ocelot
gerbil
orangutan
hamster
panther
elephant
rat
rhinoceros
tiger
hippopotamus
zebra
```

what wrong with my code that make it partially ordered.

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, see [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5gBIizwsY0).

Comment: If you want to maintain an ordered list, it's much more efficient to insert the item in the correct place at once instead of sorting it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to [bubble-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) the list. You will have to loop more than once to make it work.

This answer assumes you're doing this for educational purposes. Otherwise, as StilesCrisis suggests, use `std::sort()` and also you might prefer `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a `string*`.

Answer (score 0):

LinearOrdering does not sort the data, it just swaps some elements around.

Save yourself some trouble and call std::sort.

Comment: what the class library that i need to import to use sort?

Comment: Google it. It'll be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

problem is with your linearordering function

oid SortedList::LinearOrdering(){

```
for(int i=0; i < top ; i++){

if (arr[i] > arr[top]) {
        swap (arr[i], arr[top]);
        break; 

    }

}
```

}

Comment: your function ends up swapping only top and top-1 element which results into a partially sorted list.